# How to create a new file and dump content in it in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, file, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.6

I know JFile and write function in Joomla 1.6 but is there a similar function for Joomla 2.5 too?? I didn' t get anything in Joomla docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it's there.

You can see it in `/libraries/joomla/filesystem/file.php`

Answer (score 0):

you can import it using the following code snippet:

```
jimport( 'joomla.filesystem.file' );
```